# Ansible can connect to windows machine from localhost but not from docker container

Tags: python, docker, ansible, winrm

I can successfully ping windows host using Ansible from my localhost terminal but when trying this via a docker container, it fails with the following message:

```
flask    | fatal: [eudc2.dea.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "basic: HTTPConnectionPool(host='eudc2.dea.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbc16d50550>, 'Connection to eudc2.dea.com timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))", "unreachable": true}
```

However, when pinged via localhost:

```sh
~/Documents/Projects/user oam !5 ?6 ❯ ansible dc -m win_ping                                                                                                     
eudc2.dea.com | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I would say this means the problem is in the docker container so that's the dockerfile:

```
FROM python
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install flask uwsgi requests ansible ansible_runner pywinrm
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sshpass

CMD ["uwsgi","app.ini"]
```

This is the hostvars:

```
[dc]
eudc2.dea.com 

[dc:vars]
ansible_user='username'
ansible_password='pass'
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_port=5985
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
```

Detailed output of win_ping from docker container:

```
~/Documents/Projects/user oam !5 ?7 ❯ docker exec flask ansible -i /app/ansible/inventory/hosts dc -m win_ping -vvvv                        ✘ INT
ansible 2.10.2
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.0 (default, Oct 13 2020, 20:14:06) [GCC 8.3.0]
No config file found; using defaults
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /app/ansible/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /app/ansible/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /app/ansible/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Set default localhost to localhost
Parsed /app/ansible/inventory/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.win_ping to ansible.windows.win_ping
Loading collection ansible.windows from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/win_ping.ps1
Pipelining is enabled.
<eudc2.dea.com> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: <username_truncated> on PORT 5985 TO eudc2.dea.com
eudc2.ictv.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "basic: HTTPConnectionPool(host='eudc2.dea.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f628ecd08e0>, 'Connection to eudc2.dea.com timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
    "unreachable": true
}

~/Documents/Projects/user oam !5 ?7 ❯ docker exec flask curl eudc2.dea.com                                                                 ✘ INT
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
```

Comment: Can you run again with `-vvvv` and paste logs?  Apparently, name resolution worked but actual connection not.  Can you log into the container and try to curl on the offending URL?

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl I updated the question with the information you asked for.

Comment: Will the address ```eudc2.dea.com``` be resolved in the docker container?

Comment: @Donat it is pingable yes.

Comment: your curl test was on the default port (80).  Try on 5985: `curl eudc2.dea.com:5985/wsman`

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl same output

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that the `curl` run from within the container took 16 seconds to complete.  That looks a long time.

Ansible's WinRM timeout is 20 seconds for operations:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html

Some suggestions:

- Run a few `curl` request from within and outside the container (I'm considering the container is running on the same box as what you're calling localhost); compare the times to see they differ substantially
- Run `win_ping` multiple times from both container and localhost; does container ever work or localhost ever fails?; time the runs (`time ansible dc -m win_ping`)
- Change the configurations `ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec` and `ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec` mentioned on the link above, and see if that helps

Comment: The curl didn't complete in the 16 seconds, I just stopped it because it never does. curl never works. also increasing the timeout to 60 seconds didn't help.

Comment: mmm...  It was not clear from the output that the curl didn't complete.  Can you give more details about the setup?  Are you running your container directly on your bare metal localhost?  What's the command you're using to start it?  Also, one idea for testing: try using get_url module to grab some random webpage (google.com, for example), to confirm the problem is happening on any/all outgoing connections.